# How can I export Eagle circuits to realistic 3D models?

Tags: eaglecad

I want to export my design in Eagle 9.4.2 to realistic 3D models like these:

[image]

The issue is that when I export them to STEP files, the PCB looks like a gray block with no traces marked on it. Is it possible to achieve what I want? Note: I use Solid Edge to visualize the 3D models, and I don't use Fusion 360.

Comment: I'm curious... Why not use Fusion? It's made by the same company as Eagle and thus would probably provide better compatibility.